# Can I set failures threshold for gradle checkstyle plugin?

Tags: gradle, checkstyle

To mandate developers to fix their `checkstyle` issues, I'd like to change `ignoreFailures = true` to a threshold, and I will decrease the threshold gradually. Ideally it should be something like a ratio of `{# of checkstyle errors}` to `{# of total code lines}`, but a fixed number is desirable too. Is it possible to do that with `checkstyle` plugin of `gradle`? So that when there are more errors than the threshold, `gradle build` will fail.

Comment: No, that would be a custom task (read Checkstyle XML report, fail build if threshold exceeded).